# jQuery prev, prevUntil or closest break tag then remove

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to remove the last TWO instances of the break tags for the following code:

```
<table class="theprices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="">Link</a>
        <font>stupid font tag</font>
        <br>
        <b>Something Bold</b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="">Hidden Link</a>
        <table class="addcart"></table>
        <div>some div</div>
        <div>some other div</div>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

$('.addcart').closest('br:nth-child(1)').remove();
$('.addcart').closest('br:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('table.theprices br:last').remove();
$('table.theprices br:last').remove();
```

This uses the [:last selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) to get the last matching element and remove it.

**Edit**
I also updated the class selector. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrGq/)'s a jsFiddle.

**Edit 2**
It would be more efficient if you gave the table (or even the table cell) an ID and used that in the selector instead but you probably won't notice any difference if the HTML is this simple.

Comment: was about to add a comment about the class selector ;) good job!

Comment: It should be optimized not to look up `'.theprices'` twice.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Technically, it looks up the last `<br>` within an element with the `theprices` class. It would speed it up to add `table.theprices br:last` or better yet, put an ID on it. But I'm not sure that caching `$('.theprices')` and then running `.find('br:last')` twice would be faster than just running those two selectors.

Comment: @Drackir Yes, it would be faster. With your original solution, it will look up `.theprices` twice. If you save `$('.theprices')` into a variable, and run `.find()` on it twice, it will only look for `br:last` in that specific jQuery collection. Or you can use `.slice()`, so you have to run nothing twice :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I just ran some tests in jsFiddle and (at least in Opera) my selectors are faster than caching. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YcjfL/). I think the point is that sizzle is optimized to do basic lookups like this. I agree with you about `slice()` though, which is why I up-voted your answer. :)

Comment: @Drackir Nice jsFiddle. The point of optimizing a selector though is to make it work nice even on a quite big DOM. That is when these things [will start to count](http://jonraasch.com/blog/5-performance-tuning-tricks-for-jquery). Thanks for the upvote BTW :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Yes, of course. That's why I said above that at least adding `table` to the selector would make a difference because then it could use `getElementsByTagName()` rather than getting all elements. And using an ID would be even better because then it would just use `getElementById()`. Regardless, I think we're both just saying the same thing. :)

Comment: @Drackir OK. I still say you should not invoke the same selector twice, but save the result into a var instead, but I'll stop flooding this answer with comments.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I think the jsFiddle I linked to in my comment speaks for itself. While it may not logically seem to be efficient to do it twice, the cost of running the selector twice appears to be cheaper than the cost of caching the table and running `find()` twice. Though, I did get a chance to test it in Firefox and Chrome and in FF most of the time (8/10) it was faster and in Chrome, it wasn't faster. So I guess it's browser specific. Regardless, the difference in timing either way is negligible for a single run and I can't imagine why the OP would loop this code so it's all good! :)

Comment: @Drackir I don't know how to emphasize even more that your test case does not mean anything. The DOM consists of one single table there (of course it's quick to find it :)). Imagine a page where you have some 1000 elements. And imagine how long will it take to look up something, and then just look it up again (TWICE). Don't spread bad practices.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Ok, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YcjfL/4/)'s a non-trivial DOM situation. 100 tables, every odd one of them has the `theprices` class (so the selector will have to go through every table). In Opera, my selectors run in ~1 second, caching takes ~13 seconds. Having more elements just multiplies the extra time it takes to run `find()` twice that was in my first example, it doesn't decrease it. If you want to use `.find()` for every situation, that's fine but that doesn't mean it's always the best way to do it. The only way to know for sure is to test in the actual env and see.

Comment: And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YcjfL/5/)'s a worst-case example: 202 tables, only the last one has the class. These selectors are still faster. Although, I'm assuming that jQuery searches from the top down but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Drackir Maybe one of us should create a question about this and let the community decide. I always read everywhere not to run the same DOM query twice, save the result instead (and it sounds quite logical also). I don't know much about the inner workings of Opera either (and I don't really have time to analyze your results deeply now :)).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: In most cases, I'd agree with you, caching is the way to go. However, I think in this case, Sizzle's optimizations win out over caching. I think of it this way: `$('table.theprices br:last')` returns the one element using the highly optimized Sizzle engine. But `$('table.theprices')` returns, say, 50 tables. Then, when you run `.find()` it essentially has to loop through each of those elements to find the elements it needs. Perhaps if the selector was more complex, caching would be faster. In this case though, in my eyes at least, doing it this way is faster.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the `<br>`s are always the siblings of the table `.addcart`.

```
$('.addcart').siblings('br').slice(-2).remove();
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sKcGu/)
- Docs for [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".theprices br").eq($(".theprices br").length - 1).remove();
$(".theprices br").eq($(".theprices br").length - 1).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.addcart').parent().children('br:last').remove();
$('.addcart').parent().children('br:last').remove();
```